# how to replaceFirst(char c1, char c2)?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a String `str`

I want to replace a first char 'x' in `str` with char `b`.

```
        mCodeEditText.setText(mCodeEditText.getText().toString()
                .replaceFirst("-", s.charAt(start)));
```

I get this error:

`The method replaceFirst(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, char)`

Comment: just use `replaceFirst("x","b")`

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
str.replaceFirst("a","b");
```

as the `replaceFirst` has the arguements of string so you have to pass String as parameter.

Comment: will it effect my performance? as I have to do a "ToString()" twice every time

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 "YourString".replaceFirst("u","b");
```

whether both `parameters` are String

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass in char arguments but your method requires String. As other's have said us replaceFirst("x", "b");

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own method for replacing the first found character in your string with another character as follows.

```
public static String replaceFirstChar(String str,char firstChar,char secondChar){
    String  output = "";
    boolean flag   = false;
    for(char i:str.toCharArray()){
        if(i == firstChar && !flag){
            flag = true;
            output+=secondChar;
        }
        else
            output+=i;
    }
    return output;
}
```

*Output* for  `System.out.println(replaceFirstChar("raaesh",'a','c'));`

```
rcaesh
```